# Should I be able to remote into a machine even at the login screen

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

At work I have a laptop, windows 7, and I can remote into it.  But sometimes it needs to be restarted (or gets restarted with updates) and then I can not log into it with Remote Desktop.  This is confusing to me because I know we can do this for servers and Remote Desktop is a service so shouldn't it be running when someone is not logged in.

I wait long enough for it to reboot.  I can confirm that it is at the login screen.  I have **Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop** set.  The sleep mode is turned off when plugged in, which it is.  I have the firewall set through the Allow programs to communicate through Windows Firewall setting.

Any ideas?

If it helps: one of the other issues I have with the laptop is sometimes when I am logged in remotely, it will not connect to some network resources.  I never had this problem with my desktop (windows 7) but they took that away and gave us "better" laptops

Comment: How is the laptop hooked into the network? Wire or WiFi?

Comment: Wifi... 6 more to go.

Comment: Then my guess is it's because the Wifi client isn't reconnecting until the first time a user logs in, try it with it wired.

Comment: If you add this as an answer then I can mark it correct.  Taking it off wifi worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the remote server, change the following registry setting via regedit:

Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > System > CurrentControlSet > Control > Terminal Server. Change the value of “fDenyTSConnections” to “0″.

Then, ensure that TermServices is started automatically instead of Manual:

Navigate to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services and find Remote Desktop Configuration and Remote Desktop Services and Terminal Services (Depending on your version of Windows)

Ensure they're set to start Automatic. Default is Manual.

Comment: Thank you, this advice is helpful for any one who has not set the services to automatic but wasn't my specific issue.